# Getting a list of Contacts from Acumatica Web Services API using PHP

Tags: php, acumatica

I'm trying to use the Acumatica Web Services API to get a list of Contacts (really I'm looking to get ANYTHING, but Contacts are what I'm playing with right now).

I'm successfully able to get a SoapClient connected, but not sure what exactly to do from there to pull a list of all Contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you didn't specify Acumatica version or Webservices I'm assuming you are trying to use the "Screen WebAPI" that was in 5.2 and earlier and not the new "Contract Based API" in 5.3

With that in mind, here is an example of how to make the connection and retrieve a list of all of the contacts.

The first step is to utilize the "acuwsdl2php" helper file to generate the needed screen helper classes for PHP.

In the case of contacts:

```
php acuwsdl2php.php {url of your site}/Soap/CR302000.asmx?WSDL CR302000
```

This will create the CR302000 subfolder with a Screen.php file that is the php equivalent of the schema for the screen.

Second, here is a sample class that retrieves contact information

```
<?php
require_once('AcumaticaGate.php');

$client = new AcumaticaGate('{user}', '{password}', 'CR302000','{site}/Soap/');
$Contact_summary = $client->Schema->GetSchemaResult->ContactSummary;
$Contact_detailsummary = $client->Schema->GetSchemaResult->DetailsSummary;

$every_Contact = $Contact_summary->ServiceCommands->EveryContactID;
$Contact       = $Contact_summary->ContactID;
$Contact_fname  = $Contact_detailsummary->FirstName;
$Contact_lname  = $Contact_detailsummary->LastName;

$export_param = new Export();
$export_param->commands       = array($every_Contact, $Contact, $Contact_fname, $Contact_lname);
$export_param->filters        = array();
$export_param->breakOnError   = false;
$export_param->includeHeaders = true;
$export_param->topCount       = 0;

$export = $client->Client->Export($export_param);
print_r(var_dump($export));
```

The output here is something like this:

```
  [177]=>
  object(stdClass)#562 (1) {
    ["string"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "358"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "Anna"
      [2]=>
      string(7) "Johnson"
    }
  }
  [178]=>
  object(stdClass)#563 (1) {
    ["string"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "359"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "Yona"
      [2]=>
      string(5) "Jones"
    }
  }
```

The acuwsdl2php and AcumaticaGate files are helper files that Acumatica provided to partners.  They might also be available on the client portal for download.   A quick google for them though and I believe you can find them on a few public sites.

As a side note, these helper files were originally written for 4.x.   You should look at the 5.x guides (assuming you have 5.x) for added information on logging off of a webapi when finished calling it.

Comment: Hi.. I know this answer is old. My question is, what if I wanted to pass in a specific ContactID as opposed to getting all of them. In my case I am getting customer balances, I used this code but for customer balances, i have generated the a new Screen class for customers. So how do I pass in a specific Customer ID?